# response.addHeader() not working for firefox

Tags: security, firefox, jakarta-ee

I have following url to call my application:
http://machine.domain.com:8383/eqube70/BuildNPlay
This works great and it calles index.jsp as per my expectations.

But if my request url is changed as:
http://machine.domain.com:8383/eqube70/BuildNPlay/?--%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('you got hacked')%3C/script%3E
Then I get the alert and I am not able to get my application working. This is probably script in the request url gets executed.

In order to disallow script getting executed from url I added servlet filter and added the following code in my filter

```
private String mode = "1;mode=SAMEORIGIN";

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;
    res.addHeader("X-XSS-Protection", mode );           
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

This works great on IE and Chrome but not working on Firefox.
If I install noscript plugin for firefox then it works.
But I dont want that solution.
I there any way it can be possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, (or fortunately, depending on your point of view) Firefox doesn't natively support the X-XSS-Protection protection header, so it isn't that the header isn't being added properly, just that Firefox isn't doing anything with it.

So, you will need to continue to use NoScript in order to get client-side XSS protection on Firefox.